# Variables not gaining value in subroutines

Tags: python

The total cost wont print or gain value. I've tried running the subroutines separately but that didn't work. It will not print totalcost at all:

```
            #coffee maker program

            print("Welcome to the BartSucks Coffee App")
            print("We will guide you through the ordering process")
            print("And our amazing Barista 'Simpson' will then serve you")

            name = input("Please type in your name: ")

            print("Would you like small, medium or large?")
            size = input("Type s for small\nType m for medium\nType l for large\n")
            while size.upper() not in ("S","M","L"):
                print("You must enter s, m or l")
                size = input("Please try again\n")


            print("Would you like zero,one, two or three spoons of sugar?")  
            sugars = input("Type 0 for none\nType 1 for one\nType 2 for two\nType 3 for three\n")
            while sugars not in ("0","1","2","3"):
                print("You must enter 0, 1, 2 or 3")
                sugars = input("Please try again\n")

            print("Would you like no syrup flavouring?")
            print ("Or would you like almond, vanilla or butterscotch syrup?")  
            flavour = input("n = none\na = almond\nv = vanilla\nb = butterscotch\n")
            while flavour.upper() not in ("N","A","V","B"):
                print("You must enter n, a, v or b")
                flavour = input("Please try again\n")





 totalcost=0    
            def CoffeeSize(cs):
                cs=cs.upper()
                global totalcost
                if size =="S" or size=="s":
                 totalcost+= 2.5
                elif size=="M" or size=="m":
                 totalcost+=3.0
                elif size=="L" or size=="l":
                 totalcost+= 3.5

            def SugarAmount(sa):
                sa=sa.upper()
                global totalcost
                if sugars=="0":
                 totalcost+= 0
                elif sugars=="1":
                 totalcost+= 0.5
                elif sugars=="2":
                 totalcost+= 1.0
                elif sugars=="3":
                 totalcost+= 1.5

            def flavour(fl):
                fl=fl.upper()
                global totalcost
                if flavour=="NONE" or flavour=="none":
                 totalcost+= 0
                elif flavour=="BS" or flavour=="bs":
                 totalcost+= 1.6
                elif flavour=="V" or flavour=="v":
                 totalcost+= 0.75
                elif flavour=="A" or flavour=="a":
                 totalcost+= 1.0

                CoffeeSize(cs)
                SugarAmount(sa)
                flavour(fl)
                print(totalcost)
```

Comment: The line containing ` totalcost=0 ` is indented differently than the rest of your code. Like this, you don't have valid Python.

Comment: At least in the last function, you are comparing _the function itself_ to the values. (`if flavour=="NONE"` etc)

Comment: Also, where do `cs`, `sa` etc. come from, and why aren't you using the parameters passed to the functions but the variables from the outer scope? And why first `upper` and then check both cases anyway?

Comment: first fix your code indentation, then learn to avoid globals

Answer (score 2):

sorry im quite new to this so correct me if im wrong but i think the problem is that you are calling the functions inside a function which isnt being executed?
Also, everything apart from anything under 'if','def'... etc statements should be on the first indentation level

Your code:

```
totalcost=0
def flavour(fl):
    ...
    ...
    CoffeeSize(cs)
    SugarAmount(sa)
    flavour(fl)
    print(totalcost)
```

In Python, indentations are important and define under what statement it runs over.
As you can see, you are calling the functions on the same indentation level as the code underneath the function 'flavour', therefore it wont get executed as there isnt any other place that calls that function. Try and put this at the end of your program instead:

Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    CoffeeSize(cs)
    SugarAmount(sa)
    flavour(fl)
    print(totalcost)
```

What this does is checks to see if the program is the main program instead of being imported by something else. If it is the main/'_ *main* _' program, it will go from the start, ask the users what they want and then check to see if this program is the main one, then executes all the functions that are listed under the if statement.

Sorry if i misinterpreted your problem but i think that's what the problem is from my perspective :)
Thanks!